# Making g++ use SHLD/SHRD instructions

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, optimization, bit-shift

Consider the following code:

```
#include <limits>
#include <cstdint>

using T = uint32_t; // or uint64_t

T shift(T x, T y, T n)
{
    return (x >> n) | (y << (std::numeric_limits<T>::digits - n));
}
```

According to [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g62,options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-O3+-mtune%3Dhaswell',source:'%23include+%3Climits%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%0Ausing+T+%3D+uint32_t%3B+//+or+uint64_t%0A%0AT+shift(T+x,+T+y,+T+n)%0A%7B%0A++++return+(x+%3E%3E+n)+%7C+(y+%3C%3C+(std::numeric_limits%3CT%3E::digits+-+n))%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3), clang 3.8.1 generates the following assembly code for -O1, -O2, -O3:

```
shift(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int):
        movb    %dl, %cl
        shrdl   %cl, %esi, %edi
        movl    %edi, %eax
        retq
```

While gcc 6.2 (even with `-mtune=haswell`) generates:

```
shift(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int):
    movl    $32, %ecx
    subl    %edx, %ecx
    sall    %cl, %esi
    movl    %edx, %ecx
    shrl    %cl, %edi
    movl    %esi, %eax
    orl     %edi, %eax
    ret
```

This seems far less optimized, since [SHRD is very fast on Intel Sandybridge and later](http://agner.org/optimize/). Is there anyway to rewrite the function to facilitate optimization by compilers (and in particular gcc) and to favor the use of SHLD/SHRD assembly instructions?

Or are there any gcc `-mtune` or other options that would encourage gcc to tune better for modern Intel CPUs?

With `-march=haswell`, it emits BMI2 shlx / shrx, but still not shrd.

Comment: The difference is in fact tiny. `shrd` takes 4 cycles to resolve. `sal` takes 2.  My guess is that gcc takes 7 cycles and clang takes 5. (Skylake)  On e.g. Bulldozer gcc is faster because `sal/shr` is a single cycle and `shrd` is 8.

Comment: @Johan: Haswell: SHRD is 1uop, 3c latency, one per 1c throughput.  `SHL/SHR r,cl` is 3 uops, 2c latency, one per 2c throughput.  I forget if clang's silly 8bit mov can be eliminated at register-rename time, so clang's code is either 4c or 3c latency on SKL, with *much* better throughput.

Comment: I agree that SHRD is risky for the default `-mtune=generic`, but gcc should be using it for `-mtune=sandybridge` or higher at least.  Even on Nehalem it's only 2uops and 4c latency, and one per 1c throughput, so it's probably good for `-mtune=intel`, too.

Comment: @Johan: **oops, I was looking at `shrd r,r,i`, not `shrd r,r,cl`**.  The variable-count version is still 4 uops, with 4c latency, and not the best option when BMI2 is available.

Comment: @PeterCordes, it's a tricky document to navigate,esp because the headers are missing on follow up pages. I wish Agner would (allow) clean ups of those PDF's. Also an excel version would be nice.

Comment: with a constant shift-count, SHRD would be a competitive choice.  1c worse latency, but better throughput.  https://godbolt.org/g/fQj3zk

Comment: @Johan: I always look at the spreadsheet version, which already exists (in `.ods` format, OpenOffice, but you could easily convert it to Excel if you want).  My mistake was that I remembered testing SHRD specifically on my own SnB hardware, and that it was efficient on SnB (and that IACA was wrong for SHRD/SHLD on SnB).  But what I was remembering was the immediate-count version, so I only saw what I was expecting to see in Agner's spreadsheet. :/

Comment: Downloading now......

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that n being 0 is undefined behavior.

Comment: see https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/src/c++17/uint128_t.h#L77 (doesn't work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, I can see no way to get gcc to use the `SHRD` instruction.
You can manipulate the output that gcc generates by changing the [`-mtune` and `-march`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options) options.

> Or are there any gcc -mtune or other options that would encourage gcc to tune better for modern Intel CPUs?

Yes you can get gcc to generate [BMI2 code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets):

E.g: `X86-64 GCC6.2 -O3 -march=znver1 //AMD Zen`
Generates: (Haswell timings).

```
    code            critical path latency     reciprocal throughput
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    mov     eax, 32          *                     0.25
    sub     eax, edx         1                     0.25        
    shlx    eax, esi, eax    1                     0.5
    shrx    esi, edi, edx    *                     0.5
    or      eax, esi         1                     0.25
    ret
    TOTAL:                   3                     1.75
```

Compared with clang 3.8.1:

```
    mov    cl, dl            1                     0.25
    shrd   edi, esi, cl      4                     2
    mov    eax, edi          *                     0.25 
    ret
    TOTAL                    5                     2.25
```

Given the dependency chain here: `SHRD` is slower on Haswell, tied on Sandybridge, slower on Skylake.
The reciprocal throughput is faster for the `shrx` sequence.

So it depends, on post BMI processors gcc produces better code, pre-BMI clang wins.
`SHRD` has wildly varying timings on different processors, I can see why gcc is not overly fond of it.
Even with `-Os` (optimize for size) gcc still does not select `SHRD`.

*) Not part of the timing because either not on the critical path, or turns into a zero latency register rename.

Comment: The `mov eax,edi` (which goes away when inlining) is actually zero latency on Haswell.  And `mov eax, 32` isn't on the critical path, so the BMI2 version is actually 4c latency from the count being ready, and 3c latency from `x` being ready.

Comment: [`shlx` / `shrx` have a write-only destination](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SARX:SHLX:SHRX.html) (using VEX encoding), so they're 1c latency, but can run in parallel with each other (without a resource conflict, because they can run on p0/p6).  It's bogus to have a single "latency" column when there isn't one single dependency chain.  So the actual latency of the BMI2 version is 2c from x and y being ready, and 3c from count being ready.  (i.e. if count isn't on the critical path, the latency is only 2c).  With constant (immediate) shift-counts, SHRD would be potentially useful.

Comment: Missed that because I was blinded by the use of ESI in both. Good catch.

Comment: Yeah same here, at first.  Then I thought "wait a minute, aren't they supposed to be shifting both operands separately?".  BTW, "critical path latency" might be a good column header.  Those are still latency numbers.